# Invoking an AWS Lambda multiple ways

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am following a demo and have created an Lambda in C# that is invoked via the AWSSDK.  The Function handler looks like this:

```
  public async Task<bool> FunctionHandler(string fileName, ILambdaContext context)
```

This works just fine.  Now I want to see if I can call it using API Gateway.  I understand that in order for that to work, I need to add `APIGatewayProxyRequest` to the function signature.  Can I add that as a parameter or do I have to replace the variable 'fileName'?

How does this work when I want the function to be invoked both ways?  Directly via the SDK or through APIGateway?  Can I have one function that is invoked multiple ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lambda doesn't support function overloading, but only a specific function call. Furthermore, the main method expects to receive the content in the first argument, so it's either `APIGatewayProxyRequest` or `filename` in your example. It can be other object, based on the trigger origin, for example `S3Event`, if the Lambda function was invoked by S3.

You can define a generic method signature,  like `FunctionHandler(Stream inputStream, ILambdaContext context)`, that parse the argument `inputStream` to a `APIGatewayProxyRequest` object. 
For example:

```
Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer jsonSerializer =
new Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer();

APIGatewayProxyRequest request = 
jsonSerializer.Deserialize<APIGatewayProxyRequest>(inputStream);
```

By that you'll be able to use the same method for several trigger types.